# StringContent is sent as empty object to node

Tags: c#, node.js, serialization, json.net

I have a C# desktop that needs to use HttpClient to make a post request to my node API. The problem is that the JSON that the node app receives is different than what I am intending. I have tried using the example below and I have read from the StringContent and seen that it contains the values that I expect but it is showing up on the node app as {};

```cs
User user = new User
{
    Username = username,
    Password = password
};
StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user)); 
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("auth", content);
```

I have also tried similar code but instead of StringContent I used only string like this:

```cs
User user = new User
{
    Username = username,
    Password = password
};
StringContent content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user); 
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("auth", content);
```

But this gives me an error about Unexpected Token " in JSON at position 0;

Please help me understand how I can send a properly serialized user object. I would prefer doing this without implementing ISerializable if possible. here is my User data class:

```cs
namespace Cloud_Calendar
{
    class User
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think that it might be useful to see what my node is doing so here it is:

```
let failCount = 0;
app.all('/failAuth', (req, res) => {
  console.log("failed" + (++failCount));
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('failure to authenticate user');
});

app.post('/main', (req, res) => {   //this will be removed & replaced with routes for each action
res.send('success');
});


app.post('/auth', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/failAuth' }), (req, res) => {
//TODO: if success parse req.body to search for req.body.action variable and redirect based on value
console.log(`req.body.action: ${req.body.action}`); //this indicates desired action
  try{
    res.redirect(308, '/main');
  }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

req.body is logged as empty... is this because of the redirect?

Comment: Have you tried sending something similar to your Node.js server app via a debugging client, such as Postman? Does that work? Meaning, are you certain the error isn't on the Node.js side?

Comment: @CoolBots I have sent similar things using cURL

Comment: `PostAsJson` serializes the object! Either use `PostAsync`, or don't serialize it first. I think you're basically serializing an already serialized JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `PostAsJsonAsync` you need to pass the object as is. Internally it will serialize the object, create a `StringContent` and post that via the `HttpClient`

So either use `PostAsJsonAsync` as it was intended

```
User user = new User
{
    Username = username,
    Password = password
};
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("auth", user);
```

Or perform the serialization yourself (basically what `PostAsJsonAsync` does internally)

```
User user = new User
{
    Username = username,
    Password = password
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
StringContent content = new StringContent(josn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("auth", content);
```